# jQuery: Animating Div Resize on 'Click'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div I'm using to show the user a status. Its width is relative to the percentage (0-100). Upon click of a button, I'd like to animate the width (in pixels) of that div. Any input on the best way to go about this? I'm already using jQuery, I assume it will use that to animate? (My panel is initially hidden, hence the .live function).

```
$('#slider50').live("click", function() {

   // Animate here

    });
```

Comment: Check out jQuery UI ( http://jqueryui.com/ ) and the `.animate()` function http://api.jquery.com/animate/ . It will do what you want.

Comment: @PeeHaa I wouldn't suggest an entire UI library for animating a single element, as well as `.animate()` being available in stock jQuery.

Comment: @JamWaffles: `.animate()` is available in stock?? Did that started from 1.6.something?

Comment: @PeeHaa [Yes it is](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It's been in there since 1.0 :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles: wut? wut? OMG I always thought it was from the UI lib :P Well... you see: never too drunk to learn :)

Comment: @PeeHaa +1 for `never too drunk to learn` xD Glad I could be of help :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As stated by PeeHaa you can use the .animate() jQuery function to expand you're div's width as shown in the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKjKP/1/

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#slider").animate({
        width: '+=30px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You can use jQuery effects [jQuery Effects docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for easing effects, in addition this library will extend the $.addClass()/$.removeClass() functions to allow transition between styling changes which you can use to change width.

Comment: Is there a way to set an absolute width? Like 'width: 400px'

Comment: Of course just replace the '+=30px' with '400px' which means that it will animate from what ever value it was set originally to 400px. '+=' will always increment whatever value by what you X px or percentage.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution that I think would work would be some something similar to this:

```
$("#slider50").live("click", function() {
  $(this).slideDown();

  /*  or something like this
    $(this).animate({
      'width' : '500px',
      'height': '500px' 
    });
  */
 });
```

Hope this helps